# Find the correct entry in myqlbinlog (using Row Based Replication)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqlbinlog

I've just started testing Row Based Replication on my MySQL 5.5. databases.

I have now got the following error:

```
Could not execute Update_rows event on table dbname.tablename;  
Can't find record in 'tablename', Error_code: 1032; 
handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; 
the event's master log mysql-bin1.000941, end_log_pos 211713441;
```

So, I grab the binary log off the master and run mysqlbinlog on it:

```
c:/mysql/mysqlbinlog.exe -h127.0.0.1 -P3306 -uxxxx -pxxxxx c:/folder/mysql-bin1.000941 --base64-output=DECODE-ROWS -v --result-file=c:/folder/941.log
```

I open the file (in this case I use gvim for windows because of the size) and search for `211713441`. This returns:

```
[more of the same above]
#160915  2:05:04 server id 21  end_log_pos 211711147    Update_rows: table id 34
#160915  2:05:04 server id 21  end_log_pos 211712319    Update_rows: table id 34
#160915  2:05:04 server id 21  end_log_pos 211713441    Update_rows: table id 34
#160915  2:05:04 server id 21  end_log_pos 211714547    Update_rows: table id 34
#160915  2:05:04 server id 21  end_log_pos 211715723    Update_rows: table id 34
[more of the same below]
```

and eventually it gets to:

```
### UPDATE `dbanme`.`tablename`
### WHERE
###   @1=123
###   @2=30
###   @3=0
###   @4=''
###   @5='12345'
###   @6='6789'
###   @7=1
```

which is basically all the (hundreds of) updates listed one after the other, with no indication of which one is which.

But how do I find the one that is causing the problem on the slave? (e.g. which one is at position 211713441) There are literally hundreds of updates, one after the other.

---

I tried the same with the realy log. According to `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` I needed:

```
Relay_Log_File = slave-relay-bin.000342
Relay_Log_Pos = 103036740
```

I run mysqlbinlog on the file as above, and open it up. Search for `103036740` and I get:

```
##   @47=128
# at 103036713  
#160915  2:44:46 server id 21  end_log_pos 207893984    Xid = 117694200 
COMMIT/*!*/;
# at 103036740
#160915  2:05:04 server id 21  end_log_pos 207894043    Query   thread_id=649029478 exec_time=2438  error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1473901504/*!*/;
/*!\C utf8 *//*!*/;
SET @@session.character_set_client=33,@@session.collation_connection=33,@@session.collation_server=8/*!*/;
BEGIN
/*!*/;
# at 103036799
# at 103037130
# at 103037219
# at 103038389
```

After that there's a whole load more of the `# at 1030....` and then the file ends.